# How to send SNS email notifications for a Cloudformation stack while creating it without using lambda?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

I am working on a cloud-formation stack and I want to send the email notifications of all the cloud-formation events from SNS topic.
I have seen so many references online to use a lambda function which will forward cloud-formation events to the SNS topic. **But I don't want to use a lambda function.** Is there a solution to do it within cloud-formation only?

What I want to achieve is to send an email notification using SNS topic which is created within the cloud-formation stack and then use the same topic to send notifications after Stack is Created, updated or deleted.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot send CloudFormation template notifications to a SNS topic that is created within that same template. Topic needs to exist already on the account during validation of your CF template.

Comment: Thanks @tyron.. I have also did research all over the internet and found the same answer.

Comment: No problem @datrey. If you can, please mark this question as answered.